# TextSwitcher NullPointer errors

Tags: textview, nullpointerexception, android

I am really stuck on this.  I am trying to do a simple textswitcher which will increment a quantity and update a price based on the quantity.  Right now in my xml i have something like a TextView within a TextSwitcher just to increment the quantity.  I get the textview with `findViewById(R.id.quantity)`.

so this is what i have to find to setup the increment quantity ( I am implemementing ViewFactory)

```
switcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
switcher.setFactory(this);
quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
```

I am also overriding the makeView()

```
@Override
     public View makeView() {
        return quantity;
    }
```

Also when an increment button is pressed i increment the counter and set the text on the switcher to the current count.  Like this:

```
switcher.setText(String.valueOf(currentQuantity));
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong??  I keep getting my nullpointer at this line:

```
switcher.setFactory(this);
```

Here is the XML snippet:

```
<TextSwitcher android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/switcher">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/quantity" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </TextSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [Documentation for TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

> setText (CharSequence text) Sets the text of the next view and
>   switches to the next view. This can be used to animate the old text
>   out and animate the next text in.

Which means you will need at least two text views, one with the old text, and one to receive the new text and animate in.
The following XML should work:

```
    <TextSwitcher 
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TextSwitcher>
```

Comment: I've missunderstood "you will need at least two text views"
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Can't add more than 2 views to a ViewSwitcher` ;f

Comment: @murt Note that this answer was written in 2011, they may very well have changed the behaviour of the ViewSwitcher since then.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you called `setContentView` prior to looking for the TextSwitcher

Comment: set it to the name of your layout file.  for example, if your layout is simplelist.xml, you would call `setContentView(R.layout.simplelist)` (ideally at the start of your onCreate method)

Comment: it already is set to that. it has nothing to do with setContentView

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint immediately after you call findViewById(R.id.switcher), I'm guessing it's null.  Also, you can try moving the findViewById(R.id.quantity) before accessing switcher and see if that is null also.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm..interesting, I was just having the same problem over here. In my case there were two problems, first I was returning null from makeView. That I believe is not your case as you are getting its reference from findViewById (Beware though, sometimes this method fails and returns you a null reference, I would recommend you to put a breakpoint there and make sure you're not having a null pointer).

The second problem I had (and I think this might just be yours too) is that apparently TextSwitcher does not expect to have any child view, so you should not put a TextView inside of it as you are doing. Try removing that TextView and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same wierd issue with findViewById returning null. After a couple of hours of digging, I was finally able to nail the issue: it IS a mistake in my code. There is a good chance you are having similar mistakes.

My code was (not original code, for illustration purpose):

```
public class MyTextSwitcher extends TextSwitcher {
public MyTextSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}
```

The error is with the constructor call. Code in the constructor should be changed to the following to make things work:

```
super(context, attrs); // note the extra attrs parameter
```

The mistake (and similar mistakes in other classes) can cause all "newly" defined resources not visible to `findViewById`.

Shame on me I made the same mistakes twice today!